# A way to hide tables in HTML e-mail in inline css - only to show them later via a media query

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries, html-email

I'm working on my first mobile template for an E-mail, using media queries. So far so good, media queries is cool and I'll be surely using this in my web design projects from now on.

However, I'm running into one difficulty; I have a pretty complicated header design (background image with Facebook & youtube logos on it that link to the corresponding pages), so it's sliced in a particular way. This makes it not too easy to make into a mobile version, and I thought maybe I could fix it in a different way: use two different header tables, one shwowing on large devices, and one showing on small devices.

The mobile part is no problem, since they interpret embedded CSS quite well.

But I can't seem to hide a complete table for other mail clients. I tried display:none, position:absolute with top and left -9999px, etc...

Does anyone have a solution for this? It would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Email clients are not full blown browsers. They only support a subset of HTML/CSS if at all.

Comment: @Oded …which depends on the email-client; Thunderbird for examples incorporates the Mozilla Gecko rendering engine and is fully capable of displaying websites like is Firefox or mots other Mozilla products: But nonetheless it's true for most other email-clients. [at]blobkat When designing email templates you need to use table layouts and techniques like it's 1999…

Comment: @feeela - Exactly my point. You have pointed out one of the few exceptions. One can't write HTML emails and expect full web functionality from most email clients.

Comment: @Oded Thanks, but often there are these little tricks that work across a lot of platforms. I'm fully aware that the html & css is handicapped, I've been designing for e-mail for quite a while. My main concern is GMail & Hotmail. Maybe there's a way to make a table only 1 pixel in height or something?

Comment: Can't answer yet because I don't have enough Rep yet, but I've found a solution like this:

`style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;"`

-> I typed a full answer, can post it in... 7 hours.

Comment: Google seems to be trying **really hard** to keep us from hiding things in gmail.  It's understandable since it could easily be put to bad use, but for those of us who want to use it for layout it's frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I seem to have found the solution myself:

Inline, on the elements inside the table to be hidden in the normal, non-mobile version, I put the following properties:

```
line-height:0px;
font-size:0px;
height:0px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

I'm testing it right now with a table with one tr, one td and one p inside the td.

I put these properties on almost every element:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" id="hidden">
  <tr class="showmobile" style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td class="showmobile" style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;">
       <p class="showmobile" style="color:White; line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;">Testing this shiznit</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also give these elements the class "showmobile", which I manipulate like this in the internal stylesheet in the head:

```
tr[class="showmobile"]
        {
         line-height:125% !important;
         font-size:16px !important;
         height:30px !important;   
        }

td[class="showmobile"]
        {
         line-height:125% !important;
         font-size:16px !important;
         height:30px !important;   
        }

p[class="showmobile"]
        {
         line-height:125% !important;
         font-size:16px !important;
         height:30px !important;   
        }
```

This way of selecting the classes, I got from the awesome html email boilerplate @ http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ -> linking to this article: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3457/media-query-issues-in-yahoo-mail-mobile-email/ -> basically, it makes Yahoo mail play nice and not apply the CSS in the media query when it doesn't need to.

**CONCLUSION:** I've tested it on four platforms: GMail, Outlook 2010, Lotus Notes (I know!), and an iPhone 3G. They all give the expected result, except for Outlook, which still shows a 1 pixel line. With some smart content (coloring the text to go up in the background), this is very well hideable.

I will keep you guys up to date if I bump into any problems with certain mail clients.

Answer (score 1):

Place the table in a div html tag and add its style as **display:none !important** in the media queries.

Answer (score 1):

After quite a battle I was able to come up with this.

- You can't use height.  Gmail replaces it with min-height.
- Don't exactly match the bg color and text
- images need to be made 1px height and width and then enlarged w/ the media queries
- you still might get some elements displaying on the screen in gmail - try and  make them as unnoticable as possible

The CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobile-hide {
     width:1px !important; 
     display:none !important; 
     color:#fff;
  }
  .mobile-show {
     display:block !important;
     line-height:125% !important;
     font-size:14px !important;
     height:auto !important; 
     color:#666 !important;
  }
  .mobile-image {
     width:350px !important;
     height:446px !important;
  }
  .w800 {width:400px !important;}
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table class="w800" width="800">
...
<tr><td>
<a href="http://mylink"><img src="image.jpg" width="300" height="300" border="0" alt="My Sweet Image" /></a>
</td>

<!-- a big fat image on the right for big screens only -->
<td class="mobile-hide">
<img class="mobile-hide" src="image2.jpg" width="450" height="500" border="0" alt="" />
<span class="mobile-hide">
My Text with a <a href="http://mylink" class="mobile-hide">link</a></span>
</td></tr>
...
</table>

<!-- a new table at the bottom for small screens only, "one column" -->
<table width="400" style="width:400px; margin:0 auto;">
<tr><td class="mobile-show" style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<img class="mobile-image" src="image2.jpg" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" />
<span class="mobile-show" style="font-size:1px; color:#ffe;">
My Text with a <a href="http://mylink" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffe;" class="mobile-show">link</a></span>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set:

```
style="vertical-align:top;line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;mso-hide:all;"
```

This will give you the most invisibility across multiple email applications, then you can use media queries to reverse the effects.

litmus.com can serve as a great tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a slightly more elegant solution, that seems to work across all popular webmail & desktop email clients except Lotus Notes 6 & 7 (predictably). Here we go:

```
<style> 
   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
      .invisible { max-height: none !important; font-size: 12px !important; display: block !important; }
   }

   ...

   .invisible { max-height: 0px; font-size: 0; display: none; }
</style>
```

[Here are my results](http://conference.createsend.com/screens/r/FC7EAD3C7CCC34D2) - do you think this is a viable solution, too?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for html emails to hide and show content. Basic, easy to understand classes 'mobile' and 'desktop'. 'Mobile' is display for mobile only. 'Desktop' is display for desktop only.

```
*[class=mobile]{display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) { 
    *[class=desktop]{display:none !important;}
    *[class=mobile]{display:block !important;width:auto !important;max-height:inherit !important;overflow:visible !important;float:none !important;}
    *[class="block"]{display:block !important;padding:5px;}
}
```

But if you are looking to have your email work as you'd hope in Outlook and Gmail you've got to go a little further. These email clients are going to display the desktop version, regardless. But you don't want them to display the mobile content so wrap all your mobile content in the conditional comment shown in the example below. That'll cover you for Outlook.

To get Gmail to behave you need to zero out all your elements and expand them in the CSS which Gmail is going to completely ignore anyway. Everything inline that you don't want Gmail to show should be width: 0;max-height: 0;overflow: hidden;

That's when the CSS (example above comes into play. The second class declaration in the media query expands your block to the approprate size for display on mobile devices and Gmail hides it.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<td class="mobile" style="width: 0;max-height: 0;overflow: hidden;">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150" style="display:block;" width="100%">
</td>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Last but not least, this last part is not yet tested.. I've been having trouble getting Windows Mobile to hide what I want it to hide. I think that elaborating on my conditional comment wrap will solve the issue by changing it to be like this:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!--><![if !IEMobile]>
<td class="mobile" style="width: 0;max-height: 0;overflow: hidden;">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150" style="display:block;" width="100%">
<![endif]><!--<![endif]-->
```

But again, this last part I haven't tested yet, will be testing tomorrow actually but if anyone wants to elaborate on Windows Mobile please do. Everything else I have thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` gets stripped by gmail!

To hide tables from gmail display it as a **block** with zero height:
Set the inline style for each table to: `display:block; overflow:hidden; height: 0; max-height: 0;`

**Remember** to apply the inline style to any child tables of the hidden table also. The override class `phoneTableOnly` only needs to go on the parent table.

Example below will only show tables on devices that support media queries with a max width of 640px. Perfect for a mobile-only menu that you don't want showing on desktops & gmail.

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*Note: This stylesheet is ignored by gmail.*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        /*Restore tables:*/
        table[class="phoneTabletOnly"], table[class="phoneTabletOnly"] table {
            display: table !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
            height: auto !important;
            max-height: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="phoneTabletOnly" style="display:block; overflow:hidden; height: 0; max-height: 0;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="display:block; overflow:hidden; height: 0; max-height: 0;">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    This will be hidden in gmail.
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="display:block; overflow:hidden; height: 0; max-height: 0;">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    This will also be hidden in gmail.
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

PS. Tested in Litmus.